# laravel 5.2 creating bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to make a basic Bootstrap Carousel work within Laravel 5.2. The code below works just fine however the Carousel does not move automatically or when I click previous/ next arrows.

I think this has something to do with how I am calling the jquery.js and bootstrap.js scripts. Outside of Laravel I would just do this,

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Basically I'm attempting to do this within Laravel but its not working. Below is my attempt. Bootstrap theme works just fine and the Carousel displays but does not move. Apologies in advance as I am quite new to Laravel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="item active">
              <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First Slide">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Test Header</h1>
                      <p>Input Text Here</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
              <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second Slide">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Test Header 2</h1>
                      <p>Input Text Here</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
              <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third Slide">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Test Header 3</h1>
                      <p>Input Text Here</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

  </div>

<link rel="script" href="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}">
<link rel="script" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "The carousel does not move" means "page has no javascript". Check the path to `bootstrap.js` and `query.js` from your page.
2. Check permissions for jquery.js and bootstrap.js on your server.
3. Try to use [CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script‌​> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

4. You are trying to connect `bootstrap.js` twice - in the `<head>` and at the end of the `<body>`. Remove the first of them.
5. Use another syntax for scripts. You need to use

```
<script src="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

instead of

```
<link rel="script" href="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}">
<link rel="script" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}">
```

Comment: I have removed one of the links. Also checked the jquery.js is in my public folder in Laravel. The path should be correct but this still does not seem to work. Update: just looking into the other pathing's now.

Comment: @MoMo Can you give me the link to you page?

Comment: @MoMo  Try to open the "View page source" and then follow the link on the `bootstrap.js`. Can the browser open it?

Comment: When I follow the link on the bootstrap.js it opens it from view source.

Comment: @MoMo It looks like I need to see what happens. Can you give me a link on the page with broken carousel?

Comment: @MoMo  Your `js` files are correct but the page can not to execute them. You can try to use `<link rel="script" href="http://www.study-clutter.com/jquery.js">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` instead ot them.

Comment: @MoMo And I think you need to check permissions for `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` on your server.

Comment: I have tried it and tested, its still not working but I'm certain its the JQuery link, ill try and sort the permissions and get jquery to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I have found the problem - Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3 (I currently have version 3 installed).

Comment: @MoMo Oups, it was a typo. I mean `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @MoMo  I notice the syntax error.  You need to use `<script src="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}"></script>  <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>` instead of  `<link rel="script" href="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}"> <link rel="script" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}">`.

Comment: Ah yes I noticed that too. Did a temp fix though, used google's hosted version - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> and it now works. Will sort the local version later on.